# How to solve $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$

Tags: limits

How do you find the limit of $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{x^n}{1+x^n}$$when n goes to infinity?

I've no idea how to solve this type of questions. 
I think when $x=1$ it equals to a half and when $x$ does not equal to $1$ it equals $0$. Does that make sense?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $x=1$ you are correct.

What happens when $x > 1$? Try to input $x=2$ and see what happens.
and if $x=1/2$? try to input that to have an idea of what should happen.

You can see that if $x > 1$ then the limit equal $1$. Can you see why?

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think we can rewrite the expression into: 1/((1/x^n)+1). And then when x>1, 1/x^n tends to 0 and that's why the limit is 1. I'm not very sure what happens when 0<=x<1. Probably the limit is 0 since the numerator becomes 0?

Comment: @Elodie you are correct if x > 1. If 0<x<1 then you are right, the numerator tends to 0. This usually is not enough (if also the denominator tends to 0, there are complications) in this case though the denominator tends to 1, so the limit is indeed 0. Good job!

Answer (score 2):

Divide everything by the most-increasing variable in your numerator.

This will give you 1 as a numerator.

This will give you 1 + (1/x^n) as a denominator.

What happens to (1/x^n) as n approaches infinity? It will approach zero.

This implies that the function goes to 1 (i.e. (1/1+0) ).

Answer (score 0):

Consider the limit
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \, \frac{x^{n}}{a+ x^{n}}.
\end{align}
For the case of $0 \leq x < 1$ it can be seen that small quantities raised to powers become smaller numbers and thus $x^{n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n \rightarrow \infty$. This portion of the limit yields a zero valued result. For the case of $x > 1$ it can be seen that large values raised to powers become larger, but $1/x^{n} \rightarrow 0$. For this case 
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \, \frac{x^{n}}{1 + x^{n} } = \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \, \frac{1}{a (1/x^{n}) + 1 } = 1.
\end{align}
For the case $x = 1$ this is seen to be
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \, \frac{1^{n}}{a + 1^{n} } = \frac{1}{a+1}.
\end{align}
Hence
\begin{align}
\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \, \frac{x^{n}}{a + x^{n}} = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} 
0 & 0\leq x < 1 \\
\frac{1}{a+1} & x = 1 \\
1 & x > 1
\end{array}
\right.
\end{align}

Comment: Ah this is what I thought after getting the hint from the previous two answers. Thanks for confirming! :D